# cmd Reg Query (dword) if = (specific#) then goto () else goto ()

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, regedit

I'm trying to deploy software to a group of computers to run an installer if they do not already have a specific version that doesn't identify using GUIDs. I'll use an Adobe verion that doesn't use GUIDs as an example of what I'm trying to do.

Lets say they have Adobe 9.3 - but need Adobe 9.5
So I run a check on one of the two dwords that identify their currently installed version. Current code is as follows: (using echo responses to test)

```
:check1
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set key="HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\9.0\Installer"
set value=VersionMax
:: delims is a TAB followed by a space
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY %key% /v %value%') DO SET base=%%B
if %base%=0x90005 && goto echo1 || goto echo2
:echo1
echo "Yes"
:echo2
echo "No"
```

So, 
echo1 = True so go to next dword check (which is same key= but different value= since its another dword) if that one also matches skip installer else go to installer
echo2 = False the dword decimal doesn't equal the 9.5 version dword to run installer.

I have had no luck with this process, and I'm told I should use VBscript... but I'm told it is possible with cmd, and that is what I would prefer. 
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

set `%value2%` and `%base2%` before trying:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
:check1
set "key=HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\9.0\Installer"
set "value1=VersionMax"
set "value2=Version (?)"
:: delims is a TAB followed by a space: this are default delimiter
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "%key%" /v %value1%') DO SET "base1=%%~B"
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "%key%" /v %value2%') DO SET "base2=%%~B"
if "%base1%"=="0x90005" if "%base2%"=="9.5 (?)" goto:NoInstall
REM put your install code here
:NoInstall
REM Adobe v9 is already installed
```